# How to use vue input mask plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to use [this](https://moip.github.io/awesome-examples/) plugin in my app. I am trying to use the directive in my component like it is shown in the docs:

```
<input v-if="edit" type="text" v-mask="'999.999.999-99'">
```

But, I got:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of
>   undefined

On, expecting in the console, I could see that this is where the error happens:

```
exports.default = {
  bind: function bind(el, binding) {
    var isMoney = false;
    if (binding.value.length < 1) return; // this is where the error happens
    var inputText = getInputText(el);
```

I am importing the plugin in my component like so:

```
import AwesomeMask from 'awesome-mask';
  export default {
      props: ['data'],
      data () {
        return {
          player: this.data.data,
          edit: false,
        }
      },
      directives: {
        'mask': AwesomeMask
      }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you registering the plugin?

Comment: I have updated the question with that part.

Comment: can you make a [mcve]?  perhaps putting the JS & HTML in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) would be best...